# Can I repair CY62256 with UT62256

Tags: ttl, sram

The CY62256-55PC(SRAM) in my old computer is broken and I need a replacement for it but I can't find the same chip. The only one similar enough in my local store is UT62256CPC-70LL, HM62256ALP-12 and HM62256BLP-7, I want to know if I could use any of them as the replacement for the old chip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know how fast memory you actually need, the answer is no.

CY62256-55PC is can work with 55ns access time.

UT62256CPC-70LL has 70ns access time.
HM62256ALP-12 has 120ns access time.
HM62256BLP-7 has 70ns access time.

So if the circuit requires a chip that is capable of 55ns access time, then a slower memory won't work.

Comment: the computer's clock is around 200kHz so I don't think 70ns is gonna effect the computer

Comment: @SairextIrkaris It still depends how fast a memory location needs to be fetched to use the result when needed. The clock frequency may or may not be related to that.

Comment: I'm not really sure about the timing, but if the fetched time is not matter, it's still gonna work right?

Comment: I don't know anything about your circuit so I can't answer if it works, all I know is that the original memory is faster and you rarely put any faster memory in a circuit than you need because it costs more so there might be a good reason that 55ns memory was used instead of slower memory.

Comment: I think I'm gonna by all of them and test the compatibility, it's a old computer I want to repair and not the product I make so the cost is not matter, since the address line is difference so I think it's may have some problem and I would like to know if they are good or not because the time for the ram test take quite long and I can't use socket since it make the chip touch the top board. Thanks for the ask anyways

Comment: At the clock rate you mentioned, all of the replacements will likely work. Unless you somehow misread or misunderstood the clock rate. I’m surprised a computer using a 55ns SRAM (expensive back then!) is running with such a slow clock. 2MHz would make more sense.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica I tested and only the UT62256CPC-70LL is stable so I think the fetched time is actually matter. the slow clock is because there are 2 microprocessor and a 2 video chip in the computer and they share the same memory, they take like 4 to 6 clock for an instruction and there's only 1 8-bit bus so the system clock is around 1 or 2 MHz, I though the 200kHz of the processor is the Ram clock